# what npm command creates a dist folder in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile

I need to run nodejs project (which is a server of a react app) on a docker container and i cant find a npm command that would create a dist folder to put in the dockerfile.
i would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: It would be the same command as when running it not on docker!

Answer (score 8):

Usually the `dist/` folder is created by the build tool (webpack, vite, parcel, etc). So there's no command that just says "create this directory." If you're using [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/) then it would be `npm run build` but I believe CRA is actually outputting to a `build/` directory and not `dist/`.

Really it just depends on what you're wanting to do exactly. Are you looking for a command to build the application for the docker file? Are you looking to just have a path? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using react.  But this answer is for the Angular folks because I had the same question, but for Angular.

You type in this command -

```
ng build
```

That will create the dist folder.

Documentation can be found here -
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#building-and-serving-from-disk

Comment: Hi, question is about React, not angular

Comment: I know, I got here because I had the same question.  But I also noted in my answer that my answer is for Angular.  So if anyone else has the same Angular question, I've answered it.  So if it helps someone - great.